# Error occuring in LINQ statement in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC app.

I am trying to write a LINQ statement in a controller, but its giving an error...

```
 ViewBag.CompanyIdList = new SelectList(db.Companies.OrderBy(t => t.Name).Where(t=>t.IsDeleted!=true || t=>t.IsTransfer !=true) , "Id", "Name");
```

whats the issue ?

Issue Solved, Thanks to  [Mystere Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61164/mystere-man)

```
   ViewBag.CompanyIdList = new SelectList(db.Companies.OrderBy(t => t.Name).Where(t => (t.IsDeleted == false || t.IsDeleted == null) && (t.IsTransfered == false || t.IsTransfered == null)), "Id", "Name");
```

Comment: What is the error message? And Why are you checking `IsDeleted != true` twice?

Comment: "it's giving an error" doesn't tell us anything.  What is the error?

Comment: I have updated the query...Showing Lots of error, like, The name 't' does not exist in the current context...Invalid expression term '=>'....Invalid expression term ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem where it says t does not exist is caused by this:

```
.Where(t=>t.IsDeleted!=true || t=>t.IsTransfer !=true)
```

This should be:

```
.Where(t=>t.IsDeleted!=true || t.IsTransfer !=true)
```

You only use the lambda once in the expression.  In fact, you can shorten it to this:

```
.Where(t => !t.IsDeleted || !t.IsTransfer)
```

Comment: what if I want to put three condition for same field. like `ViewBag.CompanyIdList = new SelectList(db.Companies.OrderBy(t => t.Name).Where(t=>t.IsDeleted!=false || t.IsDeleted == null || t=>t.IsTransfer !=true) , "Id", "Name");` this also show the error...

Comment: @user1650894 - As I said, you only use the lambda once in the expression.

Comment: ya, I sued only one time in where condition, but what if I want to use three condition ? above statement shows an error.

Comment: @user1650894 - No.. apparently you don't understand what a lambda is.  `t =>` is a lambda.  You can only use it once in the expression.  You're using it twice in the expression.  That's why you get the error.  Look at what I did to fix your problem the first time, apply it again.

Comment: no if I remove lambda from where condition then it start showing the error->  The name 't' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user1650894 - Then you're doing it wrong.  It should be `.Where(t => t.IsDeleted != false || t.IsDeleted == null || t.IsTransfer != true)`

Comment: well, This works but I want to group it , like  `(t => t.IsDeleted != false || t.IsDeleted == null) && t.IsTransfer != true )` , confused about grouping, how to use lambda when we want to group it ?

Comment: @user1650894 - it's no different.  As I said, repeatedly, you only use the lambda once.  Are you not noticing a pattern?  `.Where(t => (t.IsDeleted != false || t.IsDeleted == null) && t.IsTransfer != true)`.  This is not called grouping, it's called precedence ordering.

Comment: I have already tried this, it showing the error like 'PaymentAdviceEntity.Company' does not contain a definition for 'IsTransfer' and no extension method 'IsTransfer' accepting a first argument of type 'PaymentAdviceEntity.Company' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1650894 - then you messed something up, because if the previous code that used IsTransfer worked, this code will work.  Most likely you do not have your parenthesis in the correct places.

Comment: yes  Mystere Man, I have to use one more bracket for it.... below code works...    `ViewBag.CompanyIdList = new SelectList(db.Companies.OrderBy(t => t.Name).Where(t => ((t.IsDeleted != false || t.IsDeleted == null) && t.IsTransfered != true)), "Id", "Name");`

Comment: @user1650894 - no, you don't need that extra set of parenthesis.  This should work: `ViewBag.CompanyIdList = new SelectList(db.Companies.OrderBy(t => t.Name).Where(t => (t.IsDeleted != false || t.IsDeleted == null) && t.IsTransfered != true), "Id", "Name");`